# EE3 best option for multilangual site

Tags: multi-site-manager, ee3, transcribe

Which one is best for multilangial site? Using expressionengine 3 multi site manager or transcribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using Transcribe for a while and it is simple and elegant. The support is a bit slow but most of it is self-explanatory. LTR and RTL languages play well with Transcribe.

NavEE goes hand-in with Transcribe, to solve the menus related obstacles.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is (apparently) a few weeks away from being released for EE3, Publisher is an awesome multi-language plus workflow system.  So unless you are in a rush, it might be worth waiting...   More at [Boldminded](http://www.boldminded.com) website.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Transcribe a lot, and i really like it. Publisher is ok too, but if you don't need the workflow features i'd choose Transcribe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Republic Variables or Low Variables.. if your site is simple.. i should be enough.. I'm out of the office but if you need more infos i can explain more..

Comment: Please expand on this answer; it isn't clear how it resolves the question.